# Java: How to convert/ cast a Event Handler

Tags: java, gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I have to implement com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.HasClickHandlers on a custom component with

```
class ItemTextBox extends Composite implements HasPasteEventHandler, TextArea {
```

so I have to implement

```
@Override
    public HandlerRegistration addKeyDownHandler(final KeyDownHandler handler) {
        // return textAreaWidget.addKeyDownHandler(handler);
```

}

Now I have replaced textAreaWidget which offered to addKeyDownHandler with a Summernote https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3-extras (see Summernote) which only offers a SummernoteKeyDownHandler

How do I convert that

Comment: `SummernoteClickHandler`? No such handler in [apidocs](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/extras-apidocs/org/gwtbootstrap3/extras/summernote/client/event/package-summary.html).

Comment: @Adam i mistakenly took the Click Handler as an example. I referred to the case when there are two Handlers doing the same but being of different classes.